# Making network-intensive code more robust

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have code which interacts with amazon S3 and the files transferred are usually big - couple of gigs so what suggestions can you make to make them more robust in case of failure. Also what is the (if any) general strategy for implementing robustness in network code. Is something like that acceptable in order to try an operation 3 times? Any tips are appreciated

```
public void downloadFile(String path, int retries) {
 (if retries == 3) return;
 Connection con = new ConnectToAmazon();
 try {
  con.saveFileToDisk(path, LocalDiskPath);
 } catch ( Exception) { 
  downloadFile(path, retries++);
 }
```

Comment: Does Amazon S3 allow partly file transfers? If so I'd try to implement the transfer so that it can be resumed after failure.

Comment: I agree with Gandalf. The problem here is that you only control the code on ONE end of the network pipe, so you're going to be at the mercy of S3, I'm afraid.  If S3 doesn't allow for partial file transfer and transfer resumption, then you might have to rethink architecture and try more, smaller files rather than less, larger files.  Just some thoughts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you upload using the multipart upload API more info is in the documentation

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?uploadobjusingmpu.html